# Trying to show that $\chi(G)(\chi(G) - 1) \leq 2m$, I think I'm almost there.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

As I stated, I want to show for an arbitrary graph that $\chi(G)(\chi(G) - 1) \leq 2m$, where $m$ is the number of edges and $\gamma(G)$ is the minimal number of colors needed for a valid vertex colouring. So consider an optimal colouring of $G$. My first thought was that
$$ \chi(G)(\chi(G) - 1) = \sum_{i=1}^{\chi(G)}(\chi(G)-1),$$
so we need to some over something that is $\chi(G)-1$ for each color. I was thinking if we consider an arbitrary color, and look at the neighbours of all nodes of that color, we have nodes of $\chi(G)-1$ colors. Finally you also have that a node has at most degree $\chi(G)-1$.

My problem is I can't seem to fit these puzzle pieces together to get to $2m$. Most of the inequality I try cut off too much. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Ah sorry, minimal number of colors needed for a valid vertex coloring.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't $\chi(G)$ used for edge colourings, not vertex colourings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the chromatic number of a graph is $\chi$, that means you have partitioned the set of vertices of the graph into $\chi$ components, each containing a independent set of vertices. Also between any two such components, there is at least one edge (else you could merge these components and further reduce $\chi$). So the minimum number of edges is the pairs of such components formed. Hence we have the following relation

$$\frac{\chi(\chi-1)}{2} \leq m$$

Hence your result.

Comment: Oh I see, so the $\chi(\chi-1)$ comes from all combinations of colours, where we don't need to consider a colour with itself since no edges exist between same colours. Thanks!